# Can't return instannce of a class Foo from it static method

Tags: c++

I want to return first created instannce of a class Foo(there will be really one instance created during all program life-cycle) from it static method. Here sample code:

//.h

```
#pragma once
class Foo
{
    static Foo* _firstInstance;
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
    static Foo* GetFirstFoo();
};

//.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Foo.h"

Foo::Foo()
{
    _firstInstance = this;
}


Foo::~Foo()
{
}

Foo* Foo::GetFirstFoo()
{
    return _firstInstance;
}
```

But i got next error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class Foo * Foo::_firstInstance" (?_firstInstance@Foo@@0PAV1@A)  c:\Users\Brans\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\testSt\testSt\Foo.obj  testSt
```

What is wrong? I am new in c++ but i remember that i created class instance constructor from static method without problems.

Comment: There are hundreds of duplicates of this, and this should be covered by any basic C++ introduction...

Comment: try to change the name of a class to Bar, and please don't forget to update topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static member must be also defined in a `.cpp` file:

```
Foo* Foo::_firstInstance;
```